# Split words of a string in a list

Tags: python, string, list

I need to split all the words of a string in a list. I know that the code below is wrong, but I've only managed to do this.

```
def split_sentence(sentence):
    new_list = []
    for i in sentence:
        new_list.append(i)
    return new_list


print(split_sentence("This is a test"))
```

output :

```
['T', 'h', 'i', 's', ' ', 'i', 's', ' ', 'a', ' ', 't', 'e', 's', 't']
```

wanted output:

```
['This', 'is', 'a', 'test']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
"This is a test".split()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for:

```
def split_sentence(sentence):
    new_list = sentence.split()
    return new_list
```

or, simply:

```
def split_sentence(sentence):
    return sentence.split()
```